# What is clojure.lang.Var.getRawRoot and why is it called?

Tags: optimization, clojure

I was writing a function that checks if two points can see each other on a 2D grid for a pathfinding algorithm. After profiling the code, I found that it spent 60% of its time in clojure.lang.Var.getRawRoot(). Why is this function consuming so much time and can I optimize it away?

```
(defn line-of-sight-helper [^Maze maze [x0 y0] [x1 y1]]
  "Determines if there is a line of sight from [x0 y0] to [x1 y1] in maze."
  (let [dy (int (- y1 y0))
        dx (int (- x1 x0))
        sy (int (if (neg? dy) -1 1))
        sx (int (if (neg? dx) -1 1))
        dy (int (* sy dy))
        dx (int (* sx dx))
        bias-x (int (if (pos? sx) 0 -1))
        bias-y (int (if (pos? sy) 0 -1))
        x-long (boolean (>= dx dy))
        [u0 u1 du su bias-u] (if x-long
                               [(int x0) (int x1) dx sx bias-x]
                               [(int y0) (int y1) dy sy bias-y])
        [v0 v1 dv sv bias-v] (if x-long
                               [(int y0) (int y1) dy sy bias-y]
                               [(int x0) (int x1) dx sx bias-x])
        grid (if x-long
               #(blocked? maze [%1 %2])
               #(blocked? maze [%2 %1]))]
    (loop [u0 u0
             v0 v0
             error (int 0)]
      (if (not= u0 u1)
        (let [error (+ error dv)
              too-much-error? (> error du)
              next-blocked? (grid (+ u0 bias-u) (+ v0 bias-v))
              branch3 (and too-much-error? (not next-blocked?))
              v0 (int (if branch3
                        (+ v0 sv)
                        v0))
              error (if branch3
                      (int (- error du))
                      (int error))]
          (if (and too-much-error? next-blocked?)
            false
            (if (and (not (zero? error)) next-blocked?)
              false
              (if (and (zero? dv)
                       (grid (+ u0 bias-u)
                             v0)
                       (grid (+ u0 bias-u)
                             (- v0 1)))
                false
                (recur (int (+ u0 su))
                       v0
                       error)))))
       true))))
```

Answer (score 5):

**What's happening with getVarRoot?**

I'm really surprised that any program spends much time in getRawRoot(). All this method does is return a single field from the Var, as per the source in [clojure.lang.Var](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Var.java):

```
final public Object getRawRoot(){
    return root;
}
```

In additional, it's a small final method so should be inlined by any modern JIT compiler..... basically any calls to getRawRoot should be insanely fast.

I suspect that something strange is going on with your profiler: perhaps it is adding debug code in getRawRoot() that is taking a lot of time. Hence I'd suggest benchmarking your code without the profiler and with `java -server` to see how the function really performs.

**Other performance hints**

Make sure you use **Clojure 1.3+**, since there are some optimisations for var access that you will almost certainly want to take advantage of in this kind of low-level code.

If I was to take a guess as to what is actually the biggest bottleneck in this code, then I think it would be the fact that the grid function `#(blocked? maze [%1 %2])` **constructs a new vector** every time it is called to check a grid square. It would be much better if you could refactor this so that it didn't need a vector and you could then just use `#(blocked? maze %1 %2)` directly. Constructing new collections is expensive compared to simple maths operations so you want to do it sparingly in you inner loops.

You also want to make sure you are using **primitive operations** wherever possible, and with `(set! *unchecked-math* true)`. Make sure you declare your locals as primitives, so you will want e.g. `(let [u0 (int (if x-long x0 y0)) .....] .....)` etc. The main reason to do this is avoid the overhead of boxed primitives, which again implies memory allocations that you want to avoid in inner loops.